# PHP and NuSOAP web service error?

Tags: php, web-services, android-ksoap2, nusoap

I'm using PHP and NuSOAP to create a simple web service which returns some data from a database. I've made an Android app to consume the service using ksoap2. Everything works just fine in localhost, but when i transport the service on live server (with needed modifications) i get soap fault response along with http 500 error.This is response dump in Android app.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
          xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor><faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">error in msg parsing: 
XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)</faultstring><detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm confused with this error and I can't find the cause because the request sent is completely the same when testing in localhost or on live server, but in second case it's not working. Here is request dump:

```
 <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body><n0:listAllActions id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://www.somi92.student.elab.fon.bg.ac.rs/soap/ActionList/" />
</v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

And here is my service in PHP:

```
<?php

    $server = new soap_server();
    $namespace = "http://somi92.student.elab.fon.bg.ac.rs/HSMSWebService/index.php";
    $server -> configureWSDL("ActionList");
    $server -> wsdl -> schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

$server -> register("listAllActions",
                    array(),
                    array("return" => "xsd:string"),
                    "urn:ActionList",
                    "urn:ActionList#listAllActions",
                    "rpc",
                    "literal",
                    "Get a listing of actions");

$server->service('php://input');


    function listAllActions() {

        $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        if(!$conn) 
        {
            die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
        // echo "Connected successfully!\n";

        $hsms = array(
                "desc" => "",
                "num" => "",
                "price" => "",
                "org" => "",
                "web" => "");
        $actions = array();

        $sql_query = "select HB.hb_id, HB.opis, HB.broj, HB.cena, ORG.naziv, ORG.website ".
                     "from HUMANITARNI_BROJ HB join ORGANIZACIJA ORG on (HB.org_id = ORG.org_id); ";
                     "order by HB.prioritet;";
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

        mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'");

        $result = mysql_query($sql_query, $conn);
        if(!$result) 
        {
            die("Could not execute query: ".mysql_error());
        }

        while($table_row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $hsms = array(
                    "desc" => $table_row["opis"],
                    "num" => $table_row["broj"],
                    "price" => $table_row["cena"],
                    "org" => $table_row["naziv"],
                    "web" => $table_row["website"]);
            $actions["action"][] = $hsms;
        }

        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($conn);

        return json_encode($actions);
    }

?>
```

And here is the service consumer in Android

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.somi92.student.elab.fon.bg.ac.rs/soap/ActionList/listAllActions";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.somi92.student.elab.fon.bg.ac.rs/soap/ActionList/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "listAllActions";
    private static String URL = "http://www.somi92.student.elab.fon.bg.ac.rs/HSMSWebService/index.php";
```

.....

```
SoapObject soapRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            parent.receiveData(e.getMessage()+" IO");
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("XML greska", e.getMessage());
            parent.receiveData(e.getMessage()+" XML");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            parent.receiveData(e.getMessage()+" EXC");
        }

        try {
//          SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapObject result = null;
            String message = "";

            if(envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                message = ((SoapFault)envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
            } else {
                result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            }

            if(result != null) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                parent.receiveData(obj.toString());
            } else {
                parent.receiveData("SOAP respones: "+"NULL!"+" "+message);
            }

             Log.e("dump Request: " ,androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString());
             Log.e("dump response: " ,androidHttpTransport.responseDump.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            parent.receiveData(e.getMessage()+" Error");
        }
    }
```

I'm struggling with it for a few days now, and I can't find the solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.